# Border noise removal implementation

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, filter

Are there any "border noise removal" implementations (filters) written in c, c++?

I mean some filters, which could make the tranfromation of the images in the top line, to the corresponding images in the bottom line, shown on the following picture.

An example is shown on the picture below
[image]

**EDIT**

There are a few papers about this. For ex:
http://www.dfki.uni-kl.de/~shafait/papers/Shafait-projection-based-cleanup-INMIC09.pdf

So, I wonder, if there are some already written implementations of those or similar algarithms.

Comment: IMO you must search for image segmentation algorithms rather than noise removal. You are looking for structured text. Some related work [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-02713-0_57)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) provided by OpenCV. Then you have to make a mask from the box around the text. With a semi-automatic process it's easy (ask to select the box where text is in), with a full-automatic process there is some work.

Comment: what if the contour is not closed? like on the (f) image?